# Anybody know how to achieve this spherical line effect in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

[image]

I found this icon very  interesting. I know Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Mesh, but I can't achieve perspective, angularity and roundness at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird, it looks like a mapping on a volume wrapped in a mask. The only way I can get is drawing it, with no effects.

From a blend of three lines, the middle one is thicker
[image: blend]

Rotate the blend -20º

[image: rotate]

Add two vertical lines and an horizontal to mark the "volume" border (black lines)

[image: border]

Expand the blend and expand the strokes to convert them into shapes.
Selecting the black lines one by one, Menu Object > Path > Divide objects below.
Selecting the figure with the Direct Selection Tool, must be like this:

[image: nodes]

Direct selection tool > Select all the right points > Press the E key and scale vertically from top and bottom alternatively. Do the same with the left points.

[image: scale]

Select the middle top points > press E key > scale vertically down

[image: middle]

Add a circle

[image]

Select all and mask it, menu Objet > Clipping Mask > Make

[image]

I think it can be better, but it's as close as I can arrive.